# Map within a map in react, getting unexpected token expected ","

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to iterate through an array of objects and for each object also iterate through the nested array of specs. My data structure looks something like this:

```
export const jobList = [
    {
        name: "Death Knight",
        specs:  [{name: "Blood"},
                 {name: "FrostDK"},
                 {name:"Unholy"}]
    },

    {
        name: "Shaman",
        specs: [{name:"Elemental"},
                {name:"Enhancement"},
                {name:"RestoShaman"}]
    },
```

My desired output is

**Death Knight**

Blood

FrostDK

Unholy

**Shaman**

Elemental

Enhancement

RestoShaman

Here's the problem code:

```
return(
<div className="col-sm">
   {jobList.map((job, i) =>
      <p>{job.name)</p>
      job.specs.map((spec, i) => 
         <img className="spec" src={window.location.origin + '/icons/' + spec.name + '.png'} alt={spec.name} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, i)} />
      )
   )}
</div>
)
```

This is throwing a 'Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","' on `job.specs.map`. If I remove `<p>{job.name)</p>` it lists all of the specs as expected. If I throw a comma after `<p>{job.name)</p>` then I got "'job' is not defined" on `job.specs.map`. I'm not understanding why it can't call `job.name` for each job and then run job.specs.map() afterwards.

Comment: JavaScript expressions must be interpolated with `{}` delimiters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
As you are using Jsx(javascrit xml or extension) so always cover it with {} curly bracket or you can write javascript code before return and always use key after mapping else it gives error in console
      
  return(
        <div className="col-sm">
           {jobList.map((job, i) =>
    {
<React.Fragment key={i}>
              <p>{job.name)</p>
              job.specs.map((spec, i) => 
                 <img className="spec" src={window.location.origin + '/icons/' + spec.name + '.png'} alt={spec.name} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, i)} />
              )
           )}
<React.Fragment>
        </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround

```
 job.specs.map((spec, i) => 
  <img className="spec" 
     src={window.location.origin + 
     '/icons/' + spec.name + '.png'} 
     alt={spec.name} onClick=. 
     {this.handleClick.bind(this, i)} />
 )
```

with a curly braces, like you did with *joblist.map()*

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I moved the code out of the return

```
    let list = jobList.map((job) => {
        return (
          <>
            <p>{job.name}</p>
            {job.specs.map((spec, i) => 
              <img className="spec" src={window.location.origin + '/icons/' + spec.name + '.png'} alt={spec.name} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, i)} />
            )}
          </>
        )
      })
```

And then inside the return I simply put

```
<div className="col-sm jobList">
   {list}
</div>
```

And it worked like a charm. Thanks for your input everyone!